# Trying to assign score values to cards and get a final score across multiple classes

Tags: python

So,I'm trying to basically assign different values to different cards in class Deck and use them in class Player to get a score. How could i fix this to do that? Sorry, about this again.

```py
class Deck:
...
  def Cards(self):
    for suit in ["S","C","D","H"]:
      for rank in range(1, 14):
        value = rank
        if rank == 1:
          rank = 'A'
        elif rank == 11:
          rank = 'J'
        elif rank == 12:
          rank = 'Q'
        elif rank == 13:
          rank = 'K'
        if (value == 11) or (value == 12) or (value == 13):
          value = 10
        elif rank == 1:
          value == 11
        self.__value = value 
        self.__cards.append(Card(suit, rank))
# ---------------------------------------------
class Player:
  def __init__(self, name, score):
    self.__name = name
    self.__hand = []
    self.__Deck = Deck()
    self.__score = score
...
  def draw(self, deck, CardCount):
    count = 0
    while count != CardCount
      count += 1
      self.__score += self.__value
      self.__hand.append(deck.drawCard())
    return self
```

Comment: Where are you trying to score? I expect to see some function like `def score(self, cards):` but all I see is `def draw(self, deck, ...`.

Comment: Oh I see; are you trying to sum up the total value of the `draw`?

Comment: Yeah, basically, I didn't submit all of the code, but I'm just trying to take an assigned value on each card and it add it the player's score as they draw. However, I'm trying to do it across multiple classes. The "..." just means more code I didn't add.

Comment: 1. You first check `if rank == 11`, and re-assigned `rank = 'J'`. But later check `rank == 11 or 12`. The rank may no longer be 11 at that point. 2. If you want to check if some variable equals to 11 or 12 or 13, you should write `rank == 11 or rank == 12 or rank == 13` or `rank in [11, 12, 13]`. `rank == 11 or 12 or 13` is incorrect.

Comment: 3. methods / variables names begins with `__` is discouraged, and you should only use this pattern for Python built in overload `__init__` for example. Uppercase variable is preferred to be used as name of class / typing, but not int.  4. You try to assign `__value` in a loop, this should be a mistake. 5. What is `self.__value` mean in `self.__score += self.__value`?

Comment: I made a fix to the rank issue. As for self._score += self._value, I wanted to add the value of each card to the score of player mentioned in Class Player and its __init__. The value is different for each card, so I was thinking of somehow looping through and keeping a value and then using it to be added to a player's score when they draw a card. I'm trying to figure out how to do this across the two classes.

Comment: To my understanding, `Cards` is a method of `Deck`, where `self` is the reference of `Deck` instance. `self.__value` in `Cards` method has no meaning since value is used for a single card, not for deck. And, `draw` is a function for `Player`. `self` in `draw` is a reference of `Player` instance. `self._value` still has no meaning since value is not used for some player.

Answer (score 0):

make a class card

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self,card_val,suite):
        self.card_val = card_val
        self.suit = suit
    def score(self):
        if self.card_val <= 10:
           return self.card_val
        if self.card_val == 13:
           return 11
        return 10
```

now make a hand class

```
class Hand:
    cards = []
    def score(self):
        scores = [c.score() for c in self.cards]
        aces = scores.count(11)
        total = sum(scores)
        while total > 21:
             if aces <= 0:
                 break
             aces -= 1
             total -= 10
        return total
```

then use the hand

```
h = Hand()
h.cards = [Card(13,1),Card(13,2),Card(13,3),Card(8,2)]
print(h.score())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't fully specify the Card or Deck classes, I went ahead and filled it based on what I imagined you would want. I've included what @tsh has said in the comments related to how the assign of value should work.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List
import random

@dataclass
class Card:
    suit: str
    rank: str
    value: int

@dataclass
class Deck:
    unused: List[Card]
    used: List[Card] = field(default_factory=list)

    def draw_card(self):
        random.shuffle(self.unused)
        card = self.unused.pop(0)
        self.used.append(card)
        return card, Deck(self.unused, self.used)

    @staticmethod
    def generate_deck():
        cards = []
        for suit in ["S","C","D","H"]:
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                if rank in [11, 12, 13]:
                    value = 10
                elif rank == 1:
                    value = 11
                else:
                    value = rank

                if rank == 1:
                    rank = 'A'
                elif rank == 11:
                    rank = 'J'
                elif rank == 12:
                    rank = 'Q'
                elif rank == 13:
                    rank = 'K'
                cards.append(Card(suit, str(rank), value))
        return Deck(unused=cards)
```

Note while you don't want to paste in your entire codebase, it is helpful if you provide something that is [paste-able/compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as I did above. So now for the actual question. As @tsh mentioned `self.__value` is meaningless as that suggests the value of `self` which is in this case the `Player`. Instead you want to value of the card that is drawn. See the following.

```
@dataclass
class Player:
    name: str

    def draw(self, deck, card_count):
        count = 0
        score = 0
        hand = []
        while count != card_count:
            count += 1
            card, deck = deck.draw_card()
            score += card.value
            hand.append(card)
        return deck, hand, score

deck = Deck.generate_deck()
deck, hand, score = Player("Foo").draw(deck, 5)
print(f"Hand is {hand}.")
print(f"Score is {score}")
```

Example output

```
Hand is [Card(suit='S', rank='2', value=2), Card(suit='D', rank='6', value=6), Card(suit='D', rank='Q', value=10), Card(suit='H', rank='4', value=4), Card(suit='H', rank='10', value=10)].
Score is 32
```